# How do I measure the efficiency of inline css compared to using classes

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has 20 elements just like:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000; cursor:pointer; font-size:20px; line-height:30px;">Hello</div>
```

What would be the benefits to do this below:

```
<style>
.custom_style{border:1px solid #000; cursor:pointer; font-size:20px; line-height:30px;}
</style>
<div class="custom_style">Hello</div>
<div class="custom_style">Hello</div>
<div class="custom_style">Hello</div>
...
```

Visually it's the same and, since I am not loading any external CSS file with the class `custom_style`, I am wondering how these 2 codes perform.

If it was a JS code I would be plenty of alternatives to check the efficiency of the code, but since this is pure HTML/CSS how can I check that? And if instead of 20 elements I had 200?

**EDIT
I thank you all for the help but maybe I was not clear on my question. I dont wanna know the pros/cons of inline styling. I would like to measure performance, rendering performance. Which one would render faster? And by how much? Sorry if I made you lose your time. Despite that, all answer so far are pretty clear and should be considered by people thiking about using inline/class styles.**

Comment: The only real performance difference would be the possible external css file load time.  But that's only an issue on the first load as the browser will cache it afterwards.  I know of no way to benchmark css rendering performance, and have never heard of anyone doing so.

Comment: Thanks @ErikFunkenbusch I thought there would be an easy solution to benchmark that!

Answer (score 0):

**DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) Code**

Say, if you want to change a value, `font-size: 24px`, you might do n number of times than doing once in CSS. Plus the size of the code is smaller too.

**Cascading / Overriding**

I wouldn't talk about putting the CSS in a separate file, but definitely, inline styles are frowned upon, as inline styles cannot be overridden other than using `!important`.

**Presentation / Content Separation**

You should really separate the both.

Answer (score 0):

**Inline vs Class (Selectors)**

- Selectors is the natural consequence of sharable style rules, however
  they came to CSS together with a complex selectors specificity
  concept.
- Style rules defined inline can not be reused between many nodes. They
  need to be defined and parsed over and over, even if they are exactly
  the same.
- Application of inline styles to every element from JavaScript has a
  reasonable overhead in the library layer responsible for that.
- Inline Styles are still good, when you need to animate specific
  properties of a specific element.
- Inline Styles implement only a subset of CSS. They don’t have media
  queries, keyframes, pseudo selectors etc.